# How to insert current date in row's column

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, sql-server-2008

How do I insert current date into a row's column in the "Edit data" view in MS SqlServer Mgm Studio? I want to get the equivalent value of `GetDate()` function call.

Here's an image which I hope clarifies the question:

[image: An image clarifying the question]

Comment: In case anyone wonders: it is possible to insert NULL bij pressing CTRL+0. It would be nice if there was a similar way to insert the current timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can not type function so type the date or one of following solution

- Create a default `GetDate()` on the modificationddate column on your table.
- Create a update trigger that update modificationddate column when data changes in the row.

Comment: I've added the default value. Thanks