# Adding current date time in SQL Table using SSMS Edit Mode

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add the current date time to a SQL table in edit mode?

That is, in MS SQL, when you do right click on a table and click on Edit Top 200 Rows. I would like to fill current date time in the cell.

`GETDATE()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does not work.

Comment: Do you have `constraint `on it ?

Comment: I can fill in today's date i.e. 09/16/2016 but then it ignores the time and fills in 00:00:00.000. I would like the insertion to have the correct time

Comment: is the column defined as date or datetime?

Comment: Its a DateTime field

Comment: Can you change the datatype to datetime2 and try?

Comment: Do you try with Query ?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a trigger to update the `DATETIME` column to a `GETDATE()` value when the row is modified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert current date in row's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780303/how-to-insert-current-date-in-rows-column)

Comment: For anyone watching who doesn't already know: CTRL+0 will insert a null in a column in SSMS edit mode.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't manually call GETDATE() in edit mode. Instead, add GETDATE() as the default value for the column in design mode, and refrain from adding a value to the column in edit mode. Then SQL Server will add the current date-time as the value.

Answer (score 58):

Here's something fairly quick and easy.

In a new query window execute the query, `SELECT GETDATE()`.

Select the result in the result pane and `ctrl-c` to copy it to the clipboard.

Then go back to your Edit window, and paste into the datetime cell(s).

Comment: Thank you. I like your way but it wont be accurate since there will be a time lag between copy pasting the time from one window to another.

Comment: This produced the value `2017-05-24 14:27:54.473` for me; this looks like <del>ISO format</del> [ODBC canonical format](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) with miliseconds. I suppose [ISO formats would also work](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0f28d86-fea1-40f6-b982-65f6849b9eca/how-to-code-datetimeliteral-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql)

Comment: And if your date/times are stored as UTC: `SELECT GETUTCDATE()`

Comment: Very usefull for dummy testing. Thanks!